# Merging table the table header (library(formattable))

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, ggplot2, header

Very simple question. I am using an excel sheet that has three rows for the column headings; how can I convert these two row headings into one (using `library(formattable)` )? Further, these headings don't start at the top of the sheet. Thanks

My data

```
dput(tab )
structure(list(X = c(NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 21L, 23L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 49L, 61L, 63L, 71L, 
73L, 82L, 92L, 100L, 111L), Activities = c("Label", "Personal care (1 code)", 
"Employment (1 code)", "Study (1 code)", "Social care (1 code)", 
"Sports and outdoor activities (1 code)", "Hobbies, games and computing (1 code)", 
"Mass media (1 code)", "Travel and unspecified time use (1 code)", 
"Sleep (3 codes)", "Eating (1 code)", "Other personal care (3 codes)", 
"Main Job(3 codes)", "Activities related to employment (5 codes)", 
"Food Management (5 codes)", "Informal help to other households (23 codes)", 
"Making care for textiles (5 codes)", "Gardening and pet care", 
"Shopping and services (11 codes)", "Help to an adult household member (8 codes)", 
"Social life (6 codes)", "Resting-Time out (1 code)", "Physical exercise (20 codes)", 
"Games (3 codes)", "Computing (10 codes)", "TV and Video (8 codes)", 
"Travel by purpose (30 codes)", " Punctuating activity(e.g. Unspecified time use, 8 codes)"
), Single = c("weighted indegree", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0.235837", "0.38816", "0.076923", "0.243461", "0", 
"0.188502", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.111111", "0.111111", 
"0.246246", "0", "0.125", "0.125", "0.380399", "0.535398"), X.1 = c("weighted outdegree", 
"0", "0.625", "0.076923", "1", "0.333333", "0", "0.102564", "0.619469", 
"0", "0", "0.110837", "0", "0.336016", "0.13816", "0", "0", "0", 
"0.095665", "0.085938", "0", "0", "0", "0.243243", "0", "0", 
"0", "0"), Couple = c("weighted indegree", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0.108846", "0.384462", "0.128419", "0.159138", 
"0", "0.18836", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.121739", 
"0", "0", "0.056196", "0.370312", "0.342532"), X.2 = c("weighted outdegree", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.071429", "0.069444", "0.475649", 
"0", "0", "0.215333", "0", "0.220292", "0.19494", "0.059706", 
"0.059423", "0", "0.087323", "0.128205", "0", "0", "0", "0.278261", 
"0", "0", "0", "0"), Family = c("weighted indegree", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.111111", "0.407475", "1", "0.432143", 
"0", "0.238228", "0", "0", "0.2", "0.076923", "0", "0", "0", 
"0.172414", "0", "0", "0.076923", "0.564185", "0.682906"), X.3 = c("weighted outdegree", 
"1", "0.8", "0.307692", "0", "0", "0", "0.135135", "0.58547", 
"0", "0", "0.111111", "0", "0.343254", "0.130552", "0", "0", 
"0", "0.083931", "0.103093", "0", "0", "0", "0.362069", "0", 
"0", "0", "0")), .Names = c("X", "Activities", "Single", "X.1", 
"Couple", "X.2", "Family", "X.3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-28L))
```

How the table looks like:

[image]

And how I would like to have my table

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/gt is a package in development that might help print/export/render it, not sure if that's what you need

Comment: I suggest you read the top header row and data once, then read the remaining headers separately. This will preserve cell types, e.g., not read in your numbers as character, as is happening now. You can then use something like `colnames(tab) <- paste(colnames(tab), tab[1,], sep="\n")` to make a newline-separate header row ... but I think you should probably look at solving rendering of multi-row headers separately from importing and processing the data.

Comment: If your question is solely about rendering needs, then perhaps you can add to your question how you are planning on rendering it.